# Error: "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

[image]

I tried Cleaning the project , deleted Derived Data, Reinstall pod , Restart my mac but don't seem to understand whats the problem

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working for me. I think you have problem with your **pod mylifeFilms**. Update pod using the terminal. Follow the below steps:

1. Open Terminal
2. Navigate to your Project Path
3. Type `pod update` in terminal
4. Then clean project folder

Answer (score 2):

There are billion answers for similiar questions here. You can do

```
cmd + opt + shift + k // for cleaning

pod update // for your framework update via command line
```

Also You don`t need to restart your mac. Xcode restarting is enough and still legal.